# SQL query returns incorrect value for ID column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, mysqli

I am using the following SQL query to extract content from the tables **posts**, **users** and **comments**

When I run the query on the database it correctly returns the value of 14 for the 'ID' column in the result.

However using PHP's mysqli it is returning *1* and sometimes *2*. Can anyone see any issues with the query? I've been staring at it for hours and I really don't want to do a separate query just to get the correct ID value.

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON posts.ID = comments.comment_post_id AND comments.comment_approved = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.ID = posts.post_author WHERE posts.ID = '14' AND posts.post_type = 'post' AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY comments.comment_ID DESC
```

**PHP Code:**

```
 while ($thisResult = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $thisResult['ID']; // returns 1
    echo $thisResult['post_title']; // returns the correct post title
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple tables in your query have `ID` column. Use field aliases instead of `*` in `select`. For example,

`SELECT posts.id as post_id, ..... FROM posts ....`

Or you can get the right id using `$thisResult[0]` (assuming id is the first column in `posts` table)

Comment: Sometimes can't see the wood for the trees. Looking on the DB result there is an additional ID column from the users table. *Face palm* Thank you!